# Could not find aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.1.1-6503028)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
> Could not find aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.1.1-6503028).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/4.1.1-6503028/aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows.jar

I have already the google() in my build.gradle file.

Comment: did you put aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows.jar into app/libs/

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by upgrading to Gradle 4.2.2

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same error before

to fix this I tried to delete **caches** folder in  **.gradle/bin/caches** and delete the .**gradle** and **build** folders in project tree.  **Invalidate cache/ and restart**.

After rebuilding the project, gradle will download deleted folders again.